# Two times value passed in URL

Tags: javascript, url, angularjs

I have created on page in angularjs.

inside on controller i need to open a new window but i need to pass the value in that page.

So after searching a while, i get that, to pass any scope variable to another page, i need to pass through simple url parameter only.

now here is the code of first page where on button click i am calling one angular function.

```
<a ng-click="OpenUploadWindow()" class="btn btn-mini" title="SUBMIT"></a>
```

Now inside javascript file.

```
$rootScope.OpenUploadWindow = function(){
  var appName=$rootScope.appID;
  window.open("/emo/developer/submitapp/?appName=" + appName);
}
```

Now on the /emo/developer/submitapp page url looks like this.

```
http://localhost/emo/developer/submitapp/?appName=1234#?appName=1234
```

I am not getting why its is having two times value.

And i have noticed one thing, as soon i **remove ng-controller** from "submitapp" page than its coming one time only. But if i am putting any ng-controller name than it paste two times.

Comment: you would need to post some more html i suppose. i.e. the input element that the appID i suppose

Comment: Tried window.open("/emo/developer/submitapp/" + appName);

Comment: Arvind... I can't put html more..because..its long.

Comment: 7-isnotbad, i tried that also..then also..its putting two times.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have call of OpenUploadWindow or definition of this function in your controller, so it calls twice. In anyway, adding function to rootScope bad idea, try to use simple $scope.